# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '7z' in Python

Tags: python, 7zip

```
subprocess.call(["7z", "e", "Data/test/Robert_Hilder_history.txt.7z"], stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

I got an error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '7z'

How to fix this?

Comment: You can either give the complete path to `7z` as the first element in the list, such as `"C:\\Program Files\\7z\\bin\\7z.exe"`, or add the same to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: I use MacOS and `brew install p7zip` where can I find the `PATH`? @srdg